# .Net 4 JumpTask disable "Remove from this list"

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-4.0, jump-list

I am using jumplists in .NET 4, so far I got it working fine, but I cannot make a JumpTask read only so a user cannot remove the task from the jump list. I want to remove the Pin to List and Remove from this list options. I cannot figure out how. Here is my code:

```
var jumpList = new JumpList();

var jumpTask = new JumpTask
    {
        ApplicationPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.exe"),
        IconResourcePath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.Base.dll"),
        IconResourceIndex = 2,
        Title = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.CheckForUpdates,
        CustomCategory = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.Tasks,
        Arguments = "-check",
    };

jumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpTask);

jumpTask = new JumpTask
    {
        ApplicationPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.exe"),
        IconResourcePath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.Base.dll"),
        IconResourceIndex = 5,
        Title = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.RestoreHiddenUpdates,
        CustomCategory = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.Tasks,
        Arguments = "-hidden"
    };

jumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpTask);

jumpTask = new JumpTask
    {
        ApplicationPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.exe"),
        IconResourcePath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.Base.dll"),
        IconResourceIndex = 4,
        Title = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.ViewUpdateHistory,
        CustomCategory = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.Tasks,
        Arguments = "-history",
    };

jumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpTask);

jumpTask = new JumpTask
    {
        ApplicationPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.exe"),
        IconResourcePath = Path.Combine(Utilities.AppDir, @"SevenUpdate.Base.dll"),
        IconResourceIndex = 3,
        Title = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.ChangeSettings,
        CustomCategory = SevenUpdate.Properties.Resources.Tasks,
        Arguments = "-settings",
    };

jumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpTask);

JumpList.SetJumpList(Current, jumpList);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Kate means by Tasks don't appear to be removable is that literally items that appear in the "Tasks" category cannot be removed. If you would like to remove the ability to pin or unpin items in the JumpList do not supply a CustomCategory. This will cause the items to appear in the "Tasks" category and will be unpinnable and unremovable.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to do that. Pinning, unpinning, and removing are all supposed to be in the user's control.

If you would like to add certain items (like blank starting points, or templates) independent of what the user has opened recently/frequently then I suggest adding a custom category and adding the items to that.

Comment: What I mean is like iTunes jumplist, you can't remove certain jumptasks (Go to iTunes store, Shuffle all music, etc). How can I add jumptasks without the ability for the user to pin or remove them from the list.

Comment: Tasks don't appear to be removable to me (playing with a few apps on my own machine including ones I have source code for). You might be adding destinations accidentally.